# How to extract time in HH24:MM from varchar in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in the following varchar format. I would like to extract the time based on a condition e.g. < 7:00.

```
Table1
Column: timer(varchar)
23:45
05:00
07:00
22:00

Expected output
    test
    05:00
    07:30
```

I tried the following:

```
Select *
FROM Table1
where timer < 7:00
```

However, the result is not as expected.

Comment: You really tried the SQL you posted and got any result? not an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle does not have a `time` date, so presumably the type is a string.

Use string comparisons:

```
where time < '07:00'
```

Note that the leading `0` is important!

Answer (score 1):

If this is just time and you want a proper comparison then you can convert them to `date` and compare them.

```
Select *
FROM Table1
where to_date(timer,'hh24:mi') < to_date('07:00','hh24:mi');
```

please note that your expected output contains `07:30` but it is not less than `07:00` so it will not be part of the output if you compare it with less than `07:00`.

Cheers!!